# What exactly is URL rewriting?

Tags: asp.net, http, session, url, url-rewriting

Which of them is correct definition of URL rewriting?

- Shortening of URL for end-user as [elaborated here](https://www.addedbytes.com/articles/for-beginners/url-rewriting-for-beginners/)
- Appending extra arguments to URL sent to server for session management

I am confused over which one was invented first, and which one should be **correct definition** of URL re-write?

Comment: I my opinion Too broad question for SO

Comment: @Satpal, Why too broad? It is to the point question. I couldn't find answer anywhere, that's why here. Other Stack Exchange sites don't fit well for this question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*URL rewriting* is simply what its name implies: rewriting/modification of URLs.

This *can* be used for shortening URLs, and it *can* be used for appending query parameters, but it’s not restricted to these two use cases.

Answer (score 0):

To make the URL more readable
Example www.abc.com?id=1  rewrite it to www.abc.com/1

Comment: I have already mentioned that. But, in books on "web" URL rewrite is something related to session management, where cookies cannot be an option.